# Once you have called dispose() on a FixedExtentScrollController, it can no longer be used. The relevant error-causing widget was CupertinoDatePicker

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, flutter-localizations

```
 CupertinoDatePicker(
        maximumDate: DateTime.now(),
        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
          widget.birthdate = newdate;
        },
        minimumDate: DateTime(1950),
        initialDateTime: DateTime(
            DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day),
        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
      ),
```

This error comes when I try to localize my app from one language to other.

I tried but could not find any way to resolve this.